# Há três medalhas ainda não traduzidas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: Elas acabaram de sair do forno. Ainda não decidiram nem como vai ser em inglês ainda:  [Misleading description of new Curious badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234956/229289)

Comment: @bfavaretto foi usado Google Translate? `Fez uma pergunta bem recebida em 5 dias diferentes e, manteve um registro de pergunta positivo`

Comment: @Math Não sei, não fui em que fiz. Ou foi o Gabe ou um dev (nesse último caso, altas chances de Google Translate)

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão:

> **Curioso**: Fez perguntas em 5 dias diferentes e as manteve com pontuação positiva.
>
> **Inquisitivo**: Fez perguntas em 30 dias diferentes e as manteve com pontuação positiva.
>
> **Socrático**: Fez perguntas em 100 dias diferentes e as manteve com pontuação positiva.

Comment: Acho que "e elas se mantiveram com reputação positiva" ou "e se mantiveram com reputação positiva" ficaria melhor.